# What is the Xbox 360's repair warranty term?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm debating whether or not to ship my Xbox 360 in for repair (three red lights, out of warranty, original Xbox 360).  Its warranty expired in 2008.

If I pay for Microsoft to fix it and it breaks again two days later, will they cover it? Can someone please confirm what the post-repair warranty term? 30 days? 90 days? Anything? I didn't see this explicitly mentioned on their site.

Comment: 3 red lights sounds like Red Ring Of Death.  How old is the console?

Comment: To be honest if its out of warranty fix it yourself, red rings is the easiest fix. When you get a repair I think you get a 3 month extension or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available on their site: the link to the US version is [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/repair/warranty-faq).

> What is my warranty after my console is serviced?
>
> We provide a post-service warranty for serviced consoles. The length of the warranty depends on whether the service was in-warranty or out-of-warranty as follows:
>
> **In-warranty service:** If your Xbox 360 console was serviced within the original warranty period (free repair), you receive either the balance of your original warranty or 90 days, whichever is longer.
>
> **Out-of-warranty service:** If your Xbox 360 console was serviced out of the original warranty period (paid repair), your serviced console will have a 90-day warranty.

Comment: Perfect.  That's exactly what I wanted to know.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

The warranty will continue for the remainder of your original warranty, or for 95 days after they return your fixed xbox (whichever is greater). However, if you pay to have it fixed, the automatic one-year warranty and the three-year Red Ring warranty start anew.

Comment: Sorry. I phrased the question incorrectly.  I want to know if Microsoft offers a warranty period for the box they ship back after being fixed.

Comment: They warranty will continue for the remainder of your original warranty, or for 95 days after they return your fixed xbox(whichever is greater). However if you pay to have it fixed the automatic 1 year warranty and the 3 year Red light warranty start anew